# JS: adding text to text area issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to implement a solution that was posed on this question:
[Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)

But coming unstuck.

This flat function works fine when adding some dummy text into a textarea element:

```
function add_to() {
        $('#ad_textarea').val($('#ad_textarea').val()+'test');
}
```

However, when I try to wire up this function to a variable, it breaks:

```
function add_to(word) {
            $('#ad_textarea').val($('#ad_textarea').val()+word);
    }
```

when being called from this line of code:

```
<?php foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo    "<li class='$word[0]'><a href='#' onclick='add_to('$word');'>$word</a></li>";
    } 
    ?>
```

I have looked at the outputted code, and it looks clean:

```
<li class='a'><a href='#' onclick='add_to('aardvark');'>aardvark</a></li>
```

I'm ultimately trying to get aardvark to print out in the textarea. Can anyone spot my slip up?

TIA

Comment: Doesn't look clean to me - check the quoting in the onclick part.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the value, or change quotes if you're sure it won't have any in the string itself, like this:

```
 onclick='add_to("$word");'
```

However, it'd be better to use unobtrusive script and eliminate this problem at the same time, like this:

```
<li class='a'><a href='#' class='word'>aardvark</a></li>
```

Then use script like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.word").click(function() {
    $('#ad_textarea').val($('#ad_textarea').val()+$(this).text());
  });
});
```

Or use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with a function:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.word").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    $('#ad_textarea').val(function(i, v) { return v + t; });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have unescaped single quotes in your "onclick". Either use double quotes or escape them. Or you can even use double quotes outside, single quotes inside.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"<li class='$word[0]'><a href='#' onclick='add_to('$word');'>$word</a></li>";
```

to

```
"<li class='$word[0]'><a href='#' onclick=\"add_to('$word');\">$word</a></li>";
```

and check may be it works

Actually

```
onclick='add_to('aardvark');'
```

should be

```
onclick="add_to('aardvark');"
```