# Inserting text after cursor position in text area

Tags: jquery, textarea, javascript

The script below inserts text to the end of text area. I need to change to 
insert text after current cursor position in the text area.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#addCommentImage').click(function(){
        var imageLoc = prompt('Enter the Image URL:');
        if ( imageLoc ) {
            $('#comment').val($('#comment').val() + '[img]' + imageLoc + '[/img]');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/946556#946556). The `insertAtCaret` jquery plugin seems very nice.

Comment: that actually links to an non-functioning version. The one above is the one you want. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rmDzu/2/

Answer (score 25):

if the above does not work (it didn't in my case - maybe my configuration is little bit different), here is another solution:

you can use this extension function to get the position:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if ('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if ('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

the usage is : `var position = $("#selector").getCursorPosition()`

to insert text at the position:

```
var content = $('#selector').val();
var newContent = content.substr(0, position) + "text to insert" + content.substr(position);
$('#selector').val(newContent);
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks, very useful for Angular JS implementation since insertAtCaret() modifications won't work in case of ng-model binding.

Comment: Works well to insert text at cursor position. Note that if the user has selected some text, it will insert before the selection, rather than replace it (tested in Chrome).

Comment: function getCursorPosition will change to `document.getElementById('textarea').selectionStart;` or `document.getElementById('textarea').selectionEnd;`

Answer (score 3):

I have modified various versions of these to come up with a version that places the first text before whatever you have selected and the second text after what you have selected and keep what is selected still selected. This works in chrome and FF, not in IE though.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertAtCaret: function(myValue, myValueE){
  return this.each(function(i) {
    if (document.selection) {
      //For browsers like Internet Explorer
      this.focus();
      sel = document.selection.createRange();
      sel.text = myValue + myValueE;
      this.focus();
    }
    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
      //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
      var startPos = this.selectionStart;
      var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
      var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      this.value = this.value.substring(0,     startPos)+myValue+this.value.substring(startPos,endPos)+myValueE+this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
      this.focus();
      this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
      this.selectionEnd = ((startPos + myValue.length) + this.value.substring(startPos,endPos).length);
      this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } else {
      this.value += myValue;
      this.focus();
    }
  })
    }
});
```

Usage:
`$('#box').insertAtCaret("[Before selection]", "[after]");`
Also: not claiming this as mine in any way.