# Copy & Paste plain text within HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a small templating webapp, where the authors can add placeholders within their richttext editor. To prevent errors I want to provide a list of valid placeholders which then can be copied and pasted. My problem here is the way I can restrict what get's copied.
I tried two approaches, both failed.

First of all how the list of placeholders looks like:

```
<ul class="placeholders">
    <li>${address.name}</li>
    <li>${address.street}</li>
    <li>${address.city}</li>
    <li>${address.zip}</li>
</ul>
```

1. Copy to clipboard with JS:
   This doesn't work as the clipboard cannot be accessed because of security concerns. I tried the ZeroClipboard but it's documentation is not clear for me and even the examples I found here at SO weren't helpful. I want to copy the content of the `<li>` if the user clicks on it. I tried to set instantiate with `new ZeroClipboard(jQuery('ul.placeholders li')`. But this didn't work at all. In Firefox as soon as I hover over an li the loading wheel appears.
2. Just select the whole text with a range object:
   This basically works with the selection, but when I paste it in the Rich Text Editor, Firefox und IE also paste the li tag. Again as I don't have access to the clipboard I can't control, what gets copied. And as it is a RTE, I don't have much control over how it gets pasted.

Has anyone an idea on how I could make either of the approaches work?

Comment: I messed around with the idea of copying the contents of the li the user has clicked on in a fiddle for a while, uses jquery/lacks some functionality so I won't paste as an answer, but it might be of some use to you. I cribbed the insertAtCaret from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203428/inserting-text-after-cursor-position-in-text-are%D0%B0, jsfiddle I was messing around with is http://jsfiddle.net/ngr70o5q/3/, essentially it works by catching the paste event from "Cntrl + V", if a list item is selected, insert that text, if nothing selected, paste from actual clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, this could be a third approach which actually works. I didn't think of capturing the paste event instead...