# How to add an event to newly added iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, aem, jquery-events

After a helpful comment on my previous question:
[Copy & Paste plain text within HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468445/copy-paste-plain-text-within-html)

I'm now struggling to apply this approach to a rich text editor (RTE). My application runs in a CMS environment, CQ5.6.1 in this case, but this shouldn't be relevant to the problem. Text blocks are edited within this system by double clicking on it, which opens a so called dialog where within the first tab the RTE is loaded in an iframe. So the iframe will be added to the DOM after a user interaction. How can I attach the paste event listener to this iframe?

I tried this at first.

```
jQuery(document, jQuery('iframe').contents()).on('paste', paste);
```

I can see that this approach won't work as the iframe isn't there when I call this method. So I tried to attach the load event on any added iframe. At least I though `on` would take care of this...

```
jQuery(document).on('paste', paste);
jQuery('iframe').on('load', function() {
    jQuery(this).contents().on('paste', paste);
});
```

But event the `load` event never gets fired. What am I doing wrong or is there a more elegant way?

EDIT: I also tried a third approach but still the load event never gets fired:

```
jQuery(document).on('load', 'iframe', function() {
    jQuery(this).contents().on('paste', paste);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the contents of your iframe hosted on another domain? If that's the case, the reason for you not being able to add event handlers is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Trying to circumvent it is almost pointless - I'd rather think about a different approach to your problem.

There are several [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) regarding this topic.
[Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: All content is from the same domain. I know that it won't work cross domain. But thanks for the links, I already read a few posts, but non could really answer my question yet.

Comment: Too late to edit: In most questions I found on SO the iframe is already in the DOM or is added by script itself so you already have a reference to it. My problem is, the iframe will be added from another script of the CMS. So I first need to get the event that an iframe is added and then add an event listener to its document.

Comment: Super un-cool, but you might check for newly created iframes with a timer, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page). Something like `if($('#myuniqueselector iframe').length>0){ - add event handler here - }` should go inside the function then

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is specific to my CMS (CQ 5.6.1), so I'll post it as an answer to my own question if someone has a similar issue in the future. I also add cq and aem tags to the question.

You can add a `loadcontent` listener to the richtext component where you have access to the iframe from the field:

```
loadcontent: function(field){
    jQuery(field.iframe).contents().on('paste', paste);
}
```

And the paste method:

```
var paste = function(e) {
    var pastedText = jQuery('ul.placeholders li.selected').text();
    if (pastedText != '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.innerHTML = pastedText;
    }
}
```

Nonetheless if someone finds a generic way to achieve this, please add your answer.