# Insert tag into textarea

Tags: jquery, markup, bbcode

I'm developing my own forum software, and i am now doing the editor. 
Well i want to make some tags ofc, like [b] and [i].

How can i do that? Well, i found this thread: [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)

and used this:

```
$('a').click(function() //this will apply to all anchor tags
{ 
   $('#area').val($('#area').val()+'[b][/b]'); 
})
```

But i also want to point just right between the tags, between the [b] and the [/b], how can i do that?

Comment: find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/499126/665261 - this is how to set caret position in jQuery

Comment: @Billy Okay, please set an example, i can't find anything usefull in that topic.

Comment: @Diodeus Focus between the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499126/675065)

/edit: Sorry this was already answered in the comments.

Comment: Read the comments under the question, it has already been posted.

Answer (score 0):

If this is out of scope, please just say it, but you can also select text and wrap them in the [b][/b] tags by using the [JQuery selectedText](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectedText) plugin.  I think it might be helpful for your final product (otherwise, for your question, the previous question as mentioned by Billy Moon is sufficient)

Comment: Ahh, I am really sorry, I just googled the name (I came across it a while ago and can read both languages so I tend not to think about what language things are in :S)

Comment: Here: [http://squareflower.de/downloads/jquery/selectedtext/beispiele/](http://squareflower.de/downloads/jquery/selectedtext/beispiele/) all the examples are in "programming" so it doesn't matter what language the site is in (the actual code contains English, which I think is weird...)