# Insert a CR/LF into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code:

```
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
if (e.which == 13 && isCtrl) {
   log('Ctrl CR');
} else if (e.which == 17) {
   isCtrl = true;
};
```

I need to insert a Carriage Return/Line feed where the cursor is located in the input textarea.
Now that I think about it, I should probably be using a textarea selector instead of document.onkeydown, but $('textarea').onkeydown doesn't work.

Comment: `$('textarea').keydown`, no ‘on’.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks!  I'm confused by having to learn js and jQuery together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('textarea').keydown(function (e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (e.which === 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        $this.val($this.val() + '\r\n'); // untested code (to add CRLF)
    }
});
```

#### Reference

- [`.keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)
- [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: Your solution might add it to the end, but what if the cursor is positioned in the middle?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a problem. However, there's [information enough on SO already to answer that part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534).