# How to add text to a textarea with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically the function will be similar to the "quote" function on most forums. I need to click a button to grab some text and paste that into a textarea box.

I've tried some things and they work, however, they don't work with everything. For example, they don't work when the text that I need to grab has white spaces or apostrophes or if the text is very long. Any help?

I've tried most of the solutions outlined in this thread: [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery) and they do not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
var element = $('#idofyourdomelement');
element.val(element.val() + ' foo bar added');
```

And [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ML4xY/1/) as always.

Comment: It doesn't work when the text has apostrophes. Doesn't work when it has white spaces.

Comment: @user594623, which text? The one in the textarea or theone you are adding to? Because as you can see in the live demo I provided there are white spaces in both and it works. I've also tested with apostrophes and it worked. So maybe you can show your *non-working* code?