# Need a working example on how to insert text at the cursor position in a html text area using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Need a working code example on how to insert text at the cursor position in a html text area using jquery? Read somewhere there is a plugin to accomplish but not sure how plugins work.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the plugin called? A little more detail would go a long way.

Comment: James Khoury, do you have a working example how to accomplish this? Any would do.

Comment: @BWR I posted a working example, see my post

Comment: @BWR no. Do you have a non-working example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vhew/) i made a working example that was based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/946556#946556).

http://jsfiddle.net/2vhew/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Nice post. I have never needed to do this before but your sample was so nice, I bookmarked it just in case.

Comment: How do i implement this plugin?