# Inputting emoticons in TextAreaFor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to implement some emoticons to my forum, but my JS code seems to not be working. JS:

```
$button = $('button[name="smiley"]')
$('button').on('click', function () {
$('textareafor[name="content"').append(":)")})
```

Html:

```
@using Reddit.Models
@model CreateTopicViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <section id="postForm">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTopic", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>             
                <button name="smiley">s</button>
                <div class="form-group" name="content">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "8" , name = "content" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Post Topic</button>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the deal here ? Am I on the wrong track ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're still in right track, but using `id` attribute is more preferred here since `name` attribute determines user's input name in POST request.

First, put `id` attribute on both `smiley` button & textarea:

```
<button id="smiley">s</button>

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "8", id = "content" })
```

Then you can use this script to add emoticon into textarea:

```
<script>
    $('#smiley').click(function () {
        var textarea = $('#content');
        textarea.val(textarea.val() + ":)");
    });
</script>
```

Live implementation: [.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QT8VEX).

Reference:

[How to append text to '<textarea>'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734579/how-to-append-text-to-textarea)