# Add multiples lines of text to textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add multiples lines to a textarea.

For example, this is the textarea:

> Name:
>
> Age:
>
> Hobbies:

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#my-textarea").val(
    "Name:\n\n" + 
    "Age:\n\n" + 
    "Hobbies:\n\n"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with something like:

```
$("#your-widget").val("Name:\n\nAge:\n\nHobbies:");
```