# Insert text from popup into textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a input text from an popup to a textarea on the page, defined from cursor position.

The idea is, that a user clicks a button, a popup opens, where the user can write text in an input box and then click an button to insert that text to the textarea the cursor position was in.

```
position = null;

function cursorPosition () {
 if(!window.getSelection)
 {
  position = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
 }
 else 
 {
  position = window.getSelection();
 }
}

function insertAtCaret (text)
{
 position.text = text;
}
```

In the popup window I have:

```
function onclose(text)
{
 var newtext= text;
 opener.insertAtCaret(newtext);
 window.close();
}
```

Can't make it work in chrome, only IE.... Everytime I get an

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'insertAtCaret' of object [object Window]
>   is not a function

Any idea to make it work in all browsers?

Comment: Have you tried `window.insertAtCaret = function(test) { position.text = text; }`?

Comment: It seems that it comes from your object `opener` that you want to be your object with the function `insertAtCaret` attached, but here `opener` seems to be the window... Where is defined `opener`?

Comment: Are you trying to take input from a inputbox and trying it to assign to textarea? m not clear about what you are trying to convey with cursor position..!

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to tage input from inputbox and assign it to the last textarea, where the cursor were - cursorposition is used for that.

Answer (score 2):

Below code accepts input from an inputbox and adds it to the textarea as required. It appends the inputbox value to the textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<textarea id="demo" cols="30" rows="5">
</textarea>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;

var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (name!=null)
  {
  x = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
  x = x + " Hello " + name + "! How are you today?"; // textarea value is appended here.
  document.getElementById("demo").value=x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, but there can be multiple textareas, so it must be the cursor position, which defines which textarea the text should be added to :)

Comment: M not catching the idea of cursor position, can't there be some other ideal option or way to do it..?

Comment: The position of the cursor and where it is, is where the text the writes in the popup window should show, when one is finish writing text. Dies that make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are issues with insertAtCaret in FF\Chrome, you might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/946556#946556) instead.