# Append HTML to text-area while keeping the existing text-area content, and appending to where the cursor is?

Tags: jquery

The question sounds long but I am looking for a real simple basic solution.

HTML:

```
    <textarea id="test">Hello world</textarea>

                  <a>change</a>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('a').click(function() {

        var htmlString = '<div class="football"></div>'
        var existing = jQuery('#test').text()

        $('#test').append().text(existing + htmlString).html();

    });
```

This appends the existing text with my `htmlString` variable, for one is this how I should add `htmlString` into the text-area while keeping the existing content, or is there a better way?

Also its important to me to append `htmlString` where the cursor is, it makes more sense in my live code, but you should get the idea, this kind of defeats my code above stringing both of those variables like that. So I am open to some ideas :)

Here is a fiddle for you to get a better visual of what that code does [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/232/)

Comment: This looks like a good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/946556#946556 I am still open to feedback here and answers of course...

Comment: I suggest to use .val() instead of html() when dealing for form elements... Also this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the reply taking a look now... yeah I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/233/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/F5tB8/1/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
        var input = this.get(0);
        if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
        if ('selectionStart' in input) {
            // Standard-compliant browsers
            return input.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            // IE
            input.focus();
            var sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            sel.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
            return sel.text.length - selLen;
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

$('a').click(function () {
    var htmlString = '<div class="football"></div>';
    var txt = $('#test').text();
    var cur_pos = $('#test').getCursorPosition();
    if (cur_pos != 0) {
        $('#test').val(txt.substring(0, cur_pos) + htmlString + txt.substring(cur_pos + 1));
    }else{
        $('#test').val(htmlString + txt);
    }
});
```

Comment: Holy Smokes batman this is great... just quickly looked at the fiddle and this looks right on the money, glad you came across my question.. I was just looking up selectionStart and examples for it. Looks like I got a great example here :)

Comment: Is this IE compatible I read selectionStart doesn't work well with IE, Ill test it myself here in a minuet if not, that's fine there is a workaround in this post I am reading :)

Comment: Ok thanks, one more thing I need to analyze myself, but while I have you here, any idea why when inserting the `htmlString` it removes a space in front if it? Ex. Hello world if my cursor is next the the H.. kinda like this |Hello world, when the string is inserted it erases the H...

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry check updated version http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/F5tB8/1/