# Jquery function runs only once when needed multitimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

i need one thing to know and learn.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.changetext').click(function() {
    $('.textarea').html('TEXT');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="changetext">click me</button>
<div class="textarea"></div>
```

This function add TEXT to my text area.
But i need it run many times i click it.
I'm want it add TEXT each time i click, 
Right now it works only once, second time i click no effect.
Advice please.

Comment: You will have to use `.append()` or `.html(..html() + 'TEXT')`

Comment: can you show us the html part please ?

Comment: the response is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery

Comment: replace `$('.textarea').html('TEXT');` with `$('.textarea').append('TEXT');`, the html() method replaces the inner html of the element, instead of adding to it. there's also `prepend()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` instead of `html` like:

```
$('.textarea').append('TEXT');
```

**Explanation:** `html` remove the old data and add new, while `append` keeps the old data and add the new one.

Comment: hi, if i want to use variable? that wrote on div that will be added, i know the usage on JS but not at JQ.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you set the value to `TEXT` on every click; you're not adding to the value. To do this you can use `val()`, like this:

```js
$('.changetext').click(function() {
  $('.textarea').val(function(i, v) {
    return v + 'TEXT';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<button class="changetext">Add</button>
```

You could use `append()` to update the value, but I believe this may have issues in older browsers and/or versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`html()` method overwrites/updates the old values with a new one. You can use `append()` method to *append* a new value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = ['I', 'love', 'this', 'website'];
  var counter = 0;
  $('.changetext').click(function() {
    if (words[counter]) {
      $('.textarea').append(words[counter] + " ");
    }
    counter++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='textarea'></textarea>
<div class='changetext'>
  Change text
</div>
```

Comment: hi, if i want to use variable? that wrote on div that will be added, i know the usage on JS but not at JQ.

Comment: @MarcoGanzo, what do you mean? Variable where? Variable instead of "TEXT"?

Comment: yes, i mean i need to add each time custom text, i want make variable to add each time another text, so i need something that push that word i need

Comment: @MarcoGanzo, you will have to offer an context/example. What is the logic of these words? What are you trying to achieve? I've also updated the code from my answer. I hope something like that you mean.

Comment: @MarcoGanzo, what I'm supposed to do with that link? Have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed that added , look you made this : https://jsfiddle.net/6rsqfxor/1/   i want for example var words will outputed from the html, and don't need counter. i need each div generate it own word.

Comment: @MarcoGanzo, sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. I would be better if you add a jsfiddle of your own code and tell me what have you tried and what is not working. What `div`? You need to take in consideration that you cannot append `HTML` tags inside the `textarea` element, unless you want to see them inside the textarea as texts. Please create a jsfiddle with your whole relevant code. I'm not here to code for you, but I can help you fix the code if you already have. Try to put some effort when asking something.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rsqfxor/2/  i didn't want to duplicate JQ code, asked if possible something more comfortable instead copy same code couple times

Comment: @MarcoGanzo, still doesn't make sense what you are trying to achieve. In your question you said you wanted to append some text inside a textarea. Maybe you should post another question where you should add a better explanation on what you're trying to do. and post me the link here.